# Import variables from .ts into .scss angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, angular6

I am developing an angular component and I would like to import into my scss file variables (such as colors) from my ts file and I am going throught some issues.
I have seen some examples with node-sass and webpack but are not very clear to me.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by importing variables to .scss? The ones there are usually completely related to styling and don't have anything to do with and JS (or TS) code.

Comment: Nothing make sense to import scss variables into TS file. Please re-visit your idea.

Comment: Is the other way. I would like to export my variables from my ts file to my scss file. All this is because I have the colors as an input variable in my component.

Answer (score 8):

One option is [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

This is not a SASS variable that is available in preprocessing, but rather something available in the browser during runtime. Therefore, you can get/set it with javascript, and the CSS style will update based on the variable value.

For instance, let's say your component allows you to set the text color through a javascript variable `textColor`:

**CSS:**

```
p { color: var(--text-color); }
```

**JS:**

```
element.style.setProperty("--text-color", textColor);
```

And if you want the flexibility/maintainability of variables in your SCSS -- you can have the variables point to the JS/CSS variables.

**SCSS:**

```
// _vars.scss
$text-color: var(--text-color);

// _styles.scss
p { color: $text-color }
```

Make sure to verify that this feature has the level of browser support your app needs.

Comment: you need this ... constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {} ... this.ref.nativeElement.style.setProperty('--text-color', textColor)

Answer (score 4):

have you tried ngStyle

```
 <some-element [ngStyle]="{'color': styleExp}">...</some-element>
```

and then in your .ts

```
 styleExp = 'red'
```

you can read more on it on the official docs
https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to import variables to scss files from the ts files. Instead, you can use angular angular properties ngStyle and ngClass

Answer (score 3):

```js
constructor(private elem: ElementRef){
    this.colorValue = "yellow";
    this.elem.nativeElement.style.setProperty('--text-color', colorValue);
}
```

then in the css or scss you can use --text-color variable

```
p { color: var(--text-color); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I would like to give an answer that people might be interest:

***in example.component.ts***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    @HostBinding('style.--nameOfVar') nameOfVar = 'red';
    ...
}
```

***in example.component.scss (or css)***

```
.example {
    color: var(--nameOfVar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the variable of ts file in scss, you can use `[style.yourVariable]` in HTML and this variable can be referenced in scss using `var(--yourVariable)`. Make changes from ts file and it will reflect in scss like the below given code:

Html:

```html
<div class="custom-class" [style.--default-example-color]="yourVariable"</div>
```

scss:

```scss
.custom-class{
        background-color: var(--default-example-color);
    }
```